# Why CachingConnectionFactory cache channels since channels are virtual connections？

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

As the [Doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html) says:

```
Some applications need multiple logical connections to the broker. However, it is undesirable to 
keep many TCP connections open at the same time because doing so consumes 
system resources and makes it more difficult to configure firewalls. 
AMQP 0-9-1 connections are multiplexed with channels that can be thought of as 
"lightweight connections that share a single TCP connection".

Every protocol operation performed by a client happens on a channel. 
Communication on a particular channel is completely separate from communication on another 
channel, therefore every protocol method also carries a channel ID (a.k.a. channel number), 
an integer that both the broker and clients use to figure out which channel the method is for.
```

And in spring-amqp doc,it says:

```
It is important to understand that the cache size is (by default) not a limit but is merely the number of
channels that can be cached. With a cache size of, say, 10, any number of channels can actually be in use. 
If more than 10 channels are being used and they are all returned to the cache, 
10 go in the cache. The remainder are physically closed.
```

I'm a little confused since channels are virtual connections,what does `physically closed` mean?

Based on my understanding, different channels are really just different TCP packets(Identified by a different channel ID)? And if so, Why `CachingConnectionFactory` cache channels ？ (I know my understanding must be wrong。。。)

Comment: Channels are multiplaxing for concurrent access on the same real connection. We can consider a channel as an abstraction for conversation approach - several AMQP operation in a single unit of of work. The channel is also thread-bound.

Comment: what is `multiplaxing for concurrent access on the same real connection` implementation mechanism. I still don't understand why  cache channel, does channel consume any resources?

Comment: Yes. Because this abstraction is propagated directly to RabbitMQ and that one manages channels-per-connection. So, technically we indeed have some network round trip when we create a new channel.